# How to hide combined bar or status bar totally in android 4.0 mini pc?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How do I hide the android 4.0 mini pc combined bar or Status bar programatically?

I am using the below code, but it is not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: What is "combined bar"? What is "mini pc"? Why is this tagged with an iOS tag (`uitabbarcontroller`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings->Display->hide status bar tick that to hide

Answer (score 0):

just set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` attribute on your activity in the manifest file. Sometimes programmatic window manipulations can get messy. Try this out.

Comment: go to settings have hide status bar option.